# Printing in using echo

Tags: printing, command-line

I can't printing in ubuntu 11.10 with the follow command: `echo 'it's working' >/dev/usblp0` but in Ubuntu 11.04 works fine, I'm using an usb to parallel cable converter, my printer is EPSON, and the old version of Ubuntu this command works very well, but in Ubuntu 11.10 it is not working.  What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Echoing stuff directly to the printer's USB port device sounds troublesome. You may not have permission to write to it  (can you post output of `ls -la /dev/usblp0`?). Or it may be locked by the printing daemon. Any of these things may have changed from 11.04 to 11.10; stable interfaces are provided farther up the stack, like the lpr command which has been present for decades and shields you from iffy low-level printing stuff like ports and formatting languages and even location of the printers.

Any reason why you're not using `echo "it's working" |lpr` instead? This uses the cupsd printing daemon which should do the right thing for you.

Comment: It might be in the OP's interest to issue ESC/P codes like half line feeds directly, which may be misinterpreted by CUPS.